# conditionally render a placeholder before user selects value

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to add a placeholder to a custom Input but I can't work out how to conditionaly display the input value and placeholder.

the Input works fine as is without the placeholder but when I add the placeholder and select a value it doesn't update instead the placeholder shows.

Because both the placeholder and value always have a value im not sure how to conditionally render these

**app.svelte**

```
<script>
  let placeholder = 'select a state' 
  let datas=['a','b','c']     
</script

<div>
   <CustomInput 
     placeholder={placeholder} 
   />
    {#each datas as data}
      <span class="drop__item" on:click={() => letter.state = data}>{data}</span>
    {/each}

</div>
```

**customInput.svelte**

```
<span>
 {#if placeholder.length >  0}
   {placeholder}
 {:else}
    {value}
 {/if}
</span>
```

Comment: Could you show the complete code? Your customInput.svelte does not have an input element and lacks the script section also.

Comment: Why does value always have a value?

Answer (score 1):

You have a logical error.
If you have a value, show the value. If you don't have a value, show the placeholder.

```
 {#if value}
   {value}
 {:else}
    {placeholder}
 {/if}
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/57158061ee6641b0bd466952464fb23f?version=3.20.1